# How to get SharedPreferences values inside WebViewClient?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, sharedpreferences

Hello everyone I am struggling to fetch SharedPreferences boolean values in webviewClient.
I need it to control some attributes of webview like enable zoom, cookies,etc.
I am having a error on **getBaseContext**

here is my code:

````
class WebViewClient : android.webkit.WebViewClient() {
    override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)

        val pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext())
        val zoom = pref.getBoolean("ZoomControls", false)
        val webView = view as com.winkbr.browser.activity.WebView
        webView.progressBar?.isVisible = true
        if (!zoom) {

            webView.settings.builtInZoomControls = true
        } else {
        webView.settings.displayZoomControls = false
        }

    }
} ```

Thanks in advance.
````

Answer (score 0):

try to use `Context` given by `WebView`

```
val pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(view.getContext())
```

`getBaseContext()` method belongs to [`ContextWrapper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper#getBaseContext()) class. `Activity`, `Service`, `Application` and some other components are extending it, so it is available only in these